# Complete Singly Link List C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class SinglyLinkedList
{
    struct SLL
    {
        int data;
        SLL* next;
    };

    SLL *head;

public:
    SinglyLinkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

    SLL* createNewNode()
    {
        SLL *newNode = new SLL;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->data = -1;

        return newNode;
    }

    void printLL()
    {
        SLL *temp = head;

        while(temp)
        {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        cout<<endl;
    }

    void insertAtBeginning(int n)
    {
        insertAtPos(n,0);
    }

    void insertAtEnd(int n)
    {
        insertAtPos(n,0xFF);//max position so that it will add to end
    }

    void insertAtPos(int n, int pos)
    {

        if(pos < 0)
            return;

        SLL *newNode = createNewNode();
        newNode->data = n;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = newNode;
            return;
        }

        int i = 0;
        SLL* temp = head;
        SLL* prev = temp;
        while(temp->next && i<pos)
        {
            i++;
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        if(temp->next == NULL)
        {
            temp->next = newNode;
        }

        else
        {
            newNode->next = temp;

            if(pos == 0)
                head = newNode;
            else
                prev->next = newNode;
        }
    }

    void deleteAtPos(int pos)
    {
        if(head == NULL)
            return;

        int i = 0;
        SLL* temp = head;
        SLL* prev = temp;

        SLL* nodeToDelete = NULL;

        if(pos == 0) //delete head node
        {
            nodeToDelete = head;
            head = head->next;

            delete nodeToDelete;
        }

        else
        {
            while(i<pos)
            {
                i++;
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }

            nodeToDelete = temp;
            prev->next = temp->next;

            delete nodeToDelete;
        }
    }

    void deleteLL()
    {
        SLL *temp = head;

        while(temp)
        {
            temp = head;
            head = temp->next;

            delete temp;

            temp = head;
        }

        cout<<endl;
    }

};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SinglyLinkedList ll;

    //test cases
    ll.insertAtEnd(1);
    ll.insertAtEnd(2);
    ll.insertAtEnd(3);
    ll.insertAtEnd(4);
    ll.insertAtEnd(5);
    ll.insertAtEnd(6);

    ll.printLL();

    ll.insertAtBeginning(11);
    ll.insertAtBeginning(22);
    ll.insertAtBeginning(33);
    ll.insertAtBeginning(44);
    ll.insertAtBeginning(55);
    ll.insertAtBeginning(66);
    ll.insertAtBeginning(77);

    ll.printLL();

    ll.insertAtPos(0,1);
    ll.insertAtPos(4,1);
    ll.insertAtPos(2,1);
    ll.insertAtPos(5,1);
    ll.insertAtPos(1,1);

    ll.printLL();

    ll.deleteAtPos(0);
    ll.deleteAtPos(4);
    ll.deleteAtPos(2);
    ll.deleteAtPos(5);
    ll.deleteAtPos(1);

    ll.printLL();

    ll.deleteLL();

    ll.printLL();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no d-tor or I can not see it?

Answer (score 4):

### Main Flaw

You have committed the biggest C++ sin. You have a class that contains an owned pointer `SLL *head;` but you have not done any of the resource management.

Please look up the rule of three.

Currently your code is just **broken** because you forgot this. Currently any copy of the object (through the compiler generated copy constructor or assignment operator) will mean both objects are using the same underlying list. Thus updates to one will update the other.

You don't have a destructor so your objects just leak memory when they go out of scope.

### Interface

Why are you exposing the SSL internal object via a public API?

```
SLL* createNewNode()
```

This is just a bad idea. Your container contains `int` objects the user of your object does not need to know about `SSL` objects. This leakage of scope is a massive problem in terms of maintainability.

### Code Review

Don't do this in header files.

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

If I include your header in my code you change the behavior for me. `cout` and `endl` may seem benign but it general it is a bad habit. If you want to do confine it to the closest scope you can.

Sure have a print method.

```
    void printLL()
```

But why not pass the stream you want to print on as a parameter (you can even default to `std::cout`).  But the main way to print in C++ is to use `operator<<()` so you should define this (and just make it call printLL).

Prefer `"\n"` over `std::endl`. The only difference is the extra flush. There is no need to flush any buffers. The default built in automatic flushing will flush ehenever you need. Any extra flushes that you do will just make the code less effecient.

```
        cout<<endl;
```

Your list seriously has a limit of 255 elements!

```
        insertAtPos(n,0xFF);//max position so that it will add to end
```

also 0xFF is not the maximum value that an int can hold. You may want to look up a better value.

Wht does SSL not have a constructor that takes the data value?

```
        SLL *newNode = createNewNode();
        newNode->data = n;
```

This could have been written much easier with:

```
        SSL* newNode = new SSL(n); // SSL constructor does the rest of the work.
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Loki, but hare are some more things:

## Destructor

I do not see the destructor. What happen when you destroy / `delete` the class? Answer is huge memory leak.

You definitely need to have `destructor` to release the memory and prevent memory leak.

If I read the code correctly you need following or something very similar to:

```
~SinglyLinkedList(){
   deleteLL();
}
```

## Use `const` where possible.

For example in `print` method.

```
void printLL() const{
//...
}
```

## Use private where needed

I believe `createNewNode()` must be private.

## insertAtEnd()

I might suggest you use `-1` instead of `0xFF`. What will happen if list have more than 255 elements

```
void insertAtEnd(int n)
{
    insertAtPos(n, -1); //max position so that it will add to end
}
```

## Make `typedef` for list elements.

Currently the list is using `int`. If you decide to use `long` or `unsigned`, you need to change it in 100 places in the code.

Make some `typedef` or `using` (C++11) so you to be able to change the type from one place.

It could be inside the class:

```
class SinglyLinkedList
{
public:
    using element_type = int; // C++11, change to typedef if need

private:
    struct SLL
    {
        element_type data;
        SLL* next;
    };

    SLL *head;
//...
```

Even better if you do it as `template`, but I can understand that you probably want to avoid it.

## Use `smart pointer` instead of raw pointer.

If you use `smart pointer`, then you do not need to have destructor.

I think this is some example where you learning how to work with memory management, but you need at least to explore the possibility. If you are using `std::unique_ptr`, code will **not slow down**, also will **not use additional RAM** compared normal (raw) pointer you have now.

Comment: If you class contains a raw (owned pointer) you definately can not `break rule of three`. The simplest solution is to delete them. Yes a smart pointer is an option but building a container with a smart pointer has side affects (deletion is recursive rather a loop).

Comment: What I mean is, if he adds a d-tor, the compiler will not create move and copy c-tors. class will became non-copy-able and non-movable, but will behave correctly. Now class do not release the memory back.

Comment: If he adds a destructor; then compiler will still generate the copy constructor and copy assignment operator. You need to explicitly delete them (which is obeying the rule of three). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1575369/14065

Comment: You are correct. I had no idea. But it will not work correctly anyway. Any short explanation why comity decided to work this way?

Comment: Actually if you have an owned pointer then the default constructor and assignment operator will not work properly. The is because of the shallow copy problem. The result (in most situations) will be a double delete of the pointer as the original and copy go out of scope. This is undefined behavior and liable to crash your application. PS. It behaves this way to mimic the affect of the assignment operator for structures in C (and it works correctly 99.999999999% of the time. Problems occur only with owned pointers which is why the rule of three is such a big thing. It fixes that 0.000000001%

Comment: just open this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799873/why-copy-constructor-is-generated-if-there-is-a-destructor , and give non pointer example. but probably question will be closed soon.